# icon up and down with accordion bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, icons, accordion

I try to make icon chevron down and up for my accordion with bootstrap :

I have this :

http://jsfiddle.net/HwNYB/18/

I try this js but it's doesn't work :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.accordion').on('show hide', function (n) {
    $(n.target).siblings('.accordion-heading').find('.accordion-toggle i').toggleClass('icon-chevron-up icon-chevron-down');
});
</script>
```

The chevron don't up when i click on the link.

[image: img chevron]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have an `.accordion` element ?

```
$('.accordion-group').on('show hide', function (n) {
    $(n.target).siblings('.accordion-heading').find('.accordion-toggle i').toggleClass('icon-chevron-up icon-chevron-down');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HwNYB/19/)

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into many places for this answer ( SIMPLE)

I found this

```
<div class="accordion-group">
                      <div class="accordion-heading">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#jai">
                         <span class="pull-right"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></span>
                                Jai
                        </a>
                      </div>

                      <div id="jai" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                      <div >
                        <div class="accordion-inner">
                          body content 1 
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion-group">
                      <div class="accordion-heading">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
                          <span class="pull-right"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i></span>
                                jai2
                        </a>
                      </div>

                      <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
                      <div>
                        <div class="accordion-inner">
                          body content 2
                        </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion-group">
                      <div class="accordion-heading">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse3">
                          <span class="pull-right"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i></span>
                                jai3
                        </a>
                      </div>

                      <div id="collapse3" class="accordion-body collapse">
                      <div>
                        <div class="accordion-inner">
                          body content 3
                        </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

//jquery ---
//you need to have bootstrap running

```
$('div.accordion-body').on('shown', function () { console.log($(this).parent("div").find(".icon-chevron-down").html());// this will show you html selected 
$(this).parent("div").find(".icon-chevron-down").removeClass("icon-chevron-down").addClass("icon-chevron-up");

    });

    $('div.accordion-body').on('hidden', function () { console.log(this);
         $(this).parent("div").find(".icon-chevron-up").removeClass("icon-chevron-up").addClass("icon-chevron-down");
```

//fiddler [view working example](http://jsfiddle.net/diffintact/BVmUL/46/)